# Ettercap (dns_spoof)

Tags: dns-spoofing, arp-spoofing

I need to prove to my boss that he has a vulnerability to a mitm vector on his network. To do so I have been trying to configure ettercap with dns_spoof as an example.

When I run the attack on myself I am redirected reliably, however, I cant redirect any other computers on my network (I own them all so its all good).

Does anyone know what might be causing this? I have flushed the dscache on them and still nothing.

Comment: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/ettercap-tutorial/ an step by step tutorial regarding it

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution to this problem.

I enabled packet forwarding on my kernel and the attack works great now.

```
 sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
```

Comment: You should list the command used and then mark this as accepted (thought I know there might be a delay before you can).

Comment: there is a lag till I can